# how to port rviz_imu_plugin on ros foxy

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would like to visualize my IMU(MPU6050) data on RVIZ2.
A node is publishing  message(sensor_msgs::msg::Imu) and I can see the message via "ros2 topic echo /imu" at this time.

Could you please advise how to see IMU data on RVIZ2?
It seems like that there's rviz_imu_plugin(http://wiki.ros.org/rviz_imu_plugin) but I did not find one for ros2 foxy/Rviz2

(1) environment

1. Ubuntu Version

   Distributor ID: Ubuntu
   Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
   Release:    20.04
   Codename:   focal
2. ROS version: Foxy

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/388586/how-to-port-rviz_imu_plugin-on-ros-foxy/) by [kjj3502](https://answers.ros.org/users/87174/kjj3502/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2021-10-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I can see IMU data on RIVZ2. I referred to https://github.com/ccny-ros-pkg/imu_tools

---

Originally posted by [kjj3502](https://answers.ros.org/users/87174/kjj3502/) with karma: 16 on 2021-10-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2023-05-24**:
Years passed, "binary installer" (i.e. no need to build from source by yourself) is made for some ros2 distros https://index.ros.org/p/rviz_imu_plugin/